# Firebase returning WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: firebase

I have an app that uses firebase for its data.  Everything worked fine last night and now this morning.  I am having trouble writing to a particular part of the dataset.  Returning this
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established Error.  I have no real connection issues and am able to read/write from other locations. https://www.firebase.com/test.html returns all looks good.  Some help/direction here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.  I will answer this in case others encounter.  It turns out the firebase url which is being referenced is created dynamically and instead of a fully qualified url it was being sent "http://myapp.firebaseio.comundefined".  I had disabled the initialization because I was debugging a webkit issue.  Anyway.  You may get this misleading error as a result of a malformed url.

-Eric

Comment: There were also some web socket issues related to recent Chrome releases. Those can be corrected by upgrading to [1.0.2](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.2/firebase.js).